# Alternative Description Of The Isomorphism $[C_0,[C_1,\text{Set}]]\cong[C_1,[C_0,\text{Set}]]$

Tags: category-theory, limits-colimits, yoneda-lemma

I have troubles wrapping my mind around this equation.

It is trivial to prove, but I prefer to think about the objects in $[C,\text{Set}]$ as *generalized objects over $C^\text{op}$*, motivated by the Yoneda embedding and the fact that this category is the colimit completion of $C^\text{op}$.

Is there maybe a different description of the isomorphism in question, not via currying but related to the colimit completion, or otherwise related to picture of generalized objects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this gets at what you're asking, but you could think of a functor out of $C$ as a $C$-action on a collection of objects in the codomain. Then the isomorphism in question is saying that $C_1$-structures on $C_2$-sets are equivalent to $C_2$-structures on $C_1$-sets. There are then analogues in other contexts than plain presheaf categories. For instance, an ordered group is equivalently a group object in ordered sets or an ordered object in groups. Such statements are much less trivial to abstract and prove in full generality than yours, but perhaps they lend some intuition.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this seems to hint at exactly the kind of viewpoint I want to develop.  Unfortunately, I lack the expertise to fill in all the details here.  How do you get from actions to structures?  How could I realize e.g. $C$-groups as functors $F:D\rightarrow C$?  I could chose $D$ to realize all the diagrams defining internal group objects, but I'd need $F$ to be limit-preserving in order to make this work, right?  What about ordered $C$-objects, how would a functor category realize those?

Comment: @fweth Ah, I've misled you. As you suggest, it's not possible to realize groups or orders as objects of a mere functor category. Groups require functors preserving finite products, and posets require pullbacks (in addition to finite products, or at least together with binary products.) So presheaves are actually the logically simplest kind of algebraic object: they can be interpreted in a completely arbitrary category.